# Iterating through jquery json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

can anyone help i have an external json file which I can connect and show data manually but when I iterate by data.length (which is 100) it only shows the 100th data.

here is the code

```
var url ="output.json";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  for (var i=0;i <= data.length; i++) {
    $('#stage').html('<h4>' + data[i].title + '</h4>');
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean data is a json array?

Comment: Did you check xhr response from the server? .json may be considered by browser as a static file and all requests after the first mey be taken fron cache.

Comment: simple mistake i was doing. thanks to Alastair Brown. (dumb me) when i was iterating with .html it just kept rewriting until it hit 100 and that's why i was seeing the 100th result. .append showed everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're overwriting the #stage element with every iteration.  Appending each data element might work better:

```
var url ="output.json";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  for (var i=0;i <= data.length; i++) {
    $('#stage').append('<h4>' + data[i].title + '</h4>');
  }
});
```

Comment: .html was overwriting until it hit 100. that's why i only saw 100th result. now with .append it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

I believe you replace the same content as Alastair said.

Here's a [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/32tbup98/) to show the difference.

html:

```
<div id='stage'></div>
<div id='stage-2'></div>
```

javascript:

```
var data = [{title:1},{title:2},{title:3},{title:4},{title:5}];
var htmlString = ''
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    $('#stage').html('<h4>' + data[i].title + '</h4>');
    htmlString += '<h4>' + data[i].title + '</h4>';
}
$('#stage-2').html(htmlString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url ="output.json";
var htmlString = '';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  for (var i=0;i <= data.length; i++) {
    htmlString+='<h4>' + data[i].title + '</h4>'
  }
   $('#stage').html(htmlString);
});
```

Hope this will solve your problem... Good luck :-)